# Oracle - Select all values from in clause even if there is no match

Tags: oracle, in-clause

I have a dynamic data set such as 'AAA','TTT','CCC','FFF'

I need to match this data against a column C in a table T

e.g. I have in the table T for Column C, 'AAA','BBB','DDD','FFF'

I need to return something like (show null if the value doesn't exist in Column)

```
'AAA' 
'TTT' NULL
'CCC' NULL
'FFF'
```

I don't want to drop the set into table as my data changes frequently and need to query quickly.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after ??

```
  with w_data as (
        select 'AAA' c from dual union all
        select 'TTT' c from dual union all
        select 'CCC' c from dual union all
        select 'FFF' c from dual
        ),
     w_table_t as (
        select 'AAA' c from dual union all
        select 'BBB' c from dual union all
        select 'DDD' c from dual union all
        select 'FFF' c from dual
        )
  select d.c,
         NVL2(t.c, '', 'NULL' )
    from w_data d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         w_table_t   t
         ON t.c = d.c 
  /
```

results:

```
  C   NVL2
  --- ----
  AAA
  FFF
  TTT NULL
  CCC NULL
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a large data set, theoretically this is correct but in practice very difficult for me.

Comment: ? that's why I wrote it like this .. so you can replace it with what you have. what you described in your OP looks like 2 sets of data, ie 2 tables (or even the result of a query and another table .. whatever .. 2 "sets").  w_data in my example is 1 "set", w_table_t is your "table t".  You can take out everything before the "select d.c" as it's just "fake data setup". and then in that final query replace "w_data" with your first set and "w_table_t" with your table t .... large/small it's fine .. that's the logic you described you needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**EDITED**) :

```
 with data_set as (
    select 'AAA' col from dual union 
    select 'TTT' col from dual union 
    select 'CCC' col from dual union 
    select 'FFF' col from dual
    )
 select case when d.col in (select column_C from table_T) then d.col 
 else d.col||' Null' end as col_name
 from data_set d
 /
```

Comment: This returns column data that not exists in the give set (e.g.'BBB', 'DDD') for null case but I need is 'TTT','CCC' )